# Sharing internet through a wired connection makes the host internet to drop

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, ubuntu-12.04

I have connected two computers (a laptop and a desktop), using a *wired* connection. The laptop has Ubuntu 12.10 and the desktop has windows 7. The connection is good and I'm able to share the internet from an USB modem, through the Ethernet connection, and most of the time both have internet.

The problem is that sometimes, the host (laptop connected to the USB modem), disconnects from the internet, though the desktop retains an internet connection. I have tried searching for an answer from Google, but found no answers relating the issue.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Hi there, Stack Overflow is mainly a Programming Q&A why not try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Are the workstations both connected directly to the modem, or are they daisy chained? I'm not sure from your description.